# How to override optimization level for a single package in bit-bake recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

All Yocto projects by default comes with -O2 optimization level

How to override this for a single package with -O0 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From bitbake.conf:

```
export BUILD_CFLAGS = "${BUILD_CPPFLAGS} ${BUILD_OPTIMIZATION}"
FULL_OPTIMIZATION = "-O2 -pipe ${DEBUG_FLAGS}"
DEBUG_OPTIMIZATION = "-O -fno-omit-frame-pointer ${DEBUG_FLAGS} -pipe"
SELECTED_OPTIMIZATION = "${@d.getVar(['FULL_OPTIMIZATION', 'DEBUG_OPTIMIZATION'][d.getVar('DEBUG_BUILD') == '1'])}"
```

So if you want to switch it to `-O0` for debugging purposes, just set `DEBUG_BUILD="1"` in the recipe.  If the recipe is broken with `-O2` because of bad code, override `FULL_OPTIMISATION` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer suggesting

```
DEBUG_BUILD=1
```

did not work for me.
I had to use

```
DEBUG_FLAGS="-O0"
```

Comment: How about `DEBUG_BUILD="1"`, with quotes around the 1?